# SQLite. How to SELECT values from TABLE fast?

Tags: android, sql, database, performance, sqlite

I am developing dictionary application. It requires incremental search which means that SELECTING should be fast. There are 200000+ rows. Let me, first of all explain, table structure. I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE meaning(
key TEXT, 
value TEXT, 
entries BLOB);
```

Some times ago I had this index:

```
CREATE INDEX index_key ON meaning (key)
```

This query was performed for around ~500ms which was very slow

```
SELECT value FROM meaning WHERE key LIKE 'boy%' LIMIT 100
```

Then I dropped this index, created incasesensitive index which helped to improve performance 2-3 times.

```
CREATE INDEX index_key ON meaning (key COLLATE NOCASE);
```

Now this query performing for 75ms(min) - 275(ms) which is quite slow for incremental search.

```
SELECT value FROM meaning WHERE key LIKE 'boy%' LIMIT 100
```

I have tried to optimize query according to this [post](http://joshua.perina.com/africa/gambia/fajara/post/converting-to-sqlite-and-like-query-optimization).

```
SELECT value FROM meaning WHERE key >= 'boy' AND key<'boz' LIMIT 100
```

But this query is performed for 451ms.

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT value FROM meaning WHERE key LIKE 'boy%' LIMIT 100
```

This is returning following values:

[image]

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
SELECT value FROM meaning WHERE key LIKE 'boy%' LIMIT 100
```

This is returning this value(detail column):

```
SEARCH TABLE meaning USING INDEX index_key (key>? AND key<?) (~31250 rows)
```

Actually this values did not give me some sense or key what to optimize.

Is it possible to optimize SELECTion of words to be performed in ~10ms by optimization of this query or creating another table or changing some parameters of SQLite database? Could you suggest me the best way to do this?

PS. Please, do not suggest to use FTS table. In previous version of application I have used FTS. I agree that it is extremely fast. I left FTS table idea for 2 reasons:

- It is not giving proper result(it contains the words which user do not need)
- It takes more disk space

Comment: 10 ms???  do you really need ten milliseconds?

Comment: @pskink, 10ms in my opinion, ideal case, yes it can be 20ms, however i do not know would it be okey for incremental search